# JavaFXPorts with MYSQL connection

Tags: android, javafxports

I've been reading that in the development of android if the application uses a connection using JDBC to MYSQL it may not be secure. My question is that if in the development of the application using javafxports for android we have the same problem?

If we pass a desktop application developed with javafx to an android application using javafxports, can there be security problems?

Comment: Have you seen the Gluon sample [GluonSQLite](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/gluon-SQLite)? It uses an embedded database in the mobile app. But in any case you should allow access to the backend database through your app. This related [post](http://gluonhq.com/embedding-database-cross-platform-projects/) has some insight about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know something about SQLLite but I would need to connect to a server base to have the data always updated. In any case I will read the article to get more information.